# Mirror clip placement for a tall mirror

Tags: mounting, installation, mirror

How do you choose where to place mirror clips when installing large, frameless mirrors? Is there a general rule to follow?

More specifically, I am planning to mount a 16”x72” frameless mirror in a closet, with the 72” side standing up (i.e. a body-length mirror for getting dressed). The mirror came with 6 clips, and my current plan is the following (`X` marks a clip):

```
|—X—X—|
|     |     
|     |
|     |
|     |
X     X
|     |
|     |
|     |
|     |
|—X—X—|
```

Do I need more? Different placement? (FWIW every guide I found online assumes the mirror is either square or being installed lengthways.)

Comment: If the manufacturer didn't supply info on clip placement, go with your plan. It looks fine.

Comment: Are the clips going into wall studs? Drywall anchors? A door?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the forces.

The mirror is not going to try to jump upwards.

I'd put 3 on the bottom where the weight lands, one on each of the other sides. Glass is heavy. That is, in fact, how I have mounted similar mirrors in that orientation.

[image: Mirror bottom. Credit, me.]

The mirror above is on a door, so it actually has a total of 8 clips, two on each side, one on top, three on the bottom as pictured. On a wall, 6 total is probably fine. Walls don't get opened and closed like a door.

Comment: The mirror won't try to jump upwards, but it will try to *rotate forwards* and fall out of the clips if the bottom is held in place and the top is not secured well.

Comment: @alphabet Without someone pushing it from inside the wall, one (and two more on the sides) is quite adequate to hold the top against rotation on a vertical wall. It's just sitting there. If installing on a sloped ceiling the situation would be different.